# Is there a solution for taking screenshot in python selenium webdriver along with system timestamp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I'm using Python Selenium headless browser(chrome) and I need to take screenshot of entire screen(webpage + timestamp of the system). Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Python Imaging Library](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/) to overlay text onto an image.  So basically:

1. use python's `datetime` module to get system timestamp
2. take a screenshot using Selenium WebDriver
3. use the [ImageDraw](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageDraw.html) module's [`Draw.text`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.text) method to overlay the timestamp onto the image

Comment: Perfect alternative but definitely not an answer to OP's requirement  _...take screenshot of entire screen(webpage + timestamp of the system)..._

Comment: webdriver will screenshot current viewport only.